# How to check updated file?

Tags: java, android

I have following task:

I need to connect to FTP server and download data from it. Then connect to same server and check files for updates.

I can't check it by content, because file is too big. How can I do it? I use apache.commons library, FTPClient class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `FTPClient.listFiles(String pathName)` which gets you an array of `FTPFile` objects. These contain the timestamp.